# CSS - Images cascading down and not aligning horizontally

Tags: css, image, alignment

I am trying to align images horizontally but there is a weird cascading down effect. How can I solve this?

HTML (Drupal)

```
<div class="view-content">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">        
        <span class="field-content"><a href="/country">Up Country</a></span>  
      </div>  
      <div class="views-field views-field-field-book-image">
          <div class="field-content">
              <a href="/country"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="xxx.jpg" width="126" height="192" alt="" /></a>
          </div>  
      </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.field-content img {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Image

[image]

Comment: Please include your HTML.

Comment: Add your html file also so that it will be easy to sorted out?

Comment: @Soorapadman Added in the question

Comment: @purpledot in which way it's been wired .?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara Not following, what do you mean in which way it's been wired?

Comment: @purpledot what is your desired out put..? please specify in question i mean that

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara To align the title/images horizontally. (in a straight horizontal line -------- and not in the downward effect it's doing now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi as you said here is the solution may be what you want please look out the code

```css
.view-content{
    display:block;
}
.views-row{
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
.views-field.views-field-title {
    text-align: center;
}
.field-content img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-content">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">        
        <span class="field-content"><a href="/country">Up Country</a></span>  
      </div>  
      <div class="views-field views-field-field-book-image">
          <div class="field-content">
              <a href="/country">
<img src="http://www.iconpng.com/png/stickers/books.png" alt="Smiley face">
</a>

          </div>  
      </div>  
  </div>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">        
        <span class="field-content"><a href="/country">Up Country</a></span>  
      </div>  
      <div class="views-field views-field-field-book-image">
          <div class="field-content">
              <a href="/country">
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/itzikgur/my-seven/512/Books-2-icon.png" alt="Smiley face">
</a>

          </div>  
      </div>  
  </div>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">        
        <span class="field-content"><a href="/country">Up Country</a></span>  
      </div>  
      <div class="views-field views-field-field-book-image">
          <div class="field-content">
              <a href="/country">
<img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/simple-black-square-icons-culture/126872-simple-black-square-icon-culture-books3-stacked.png" alt="Smiley face">
</a>

          </div>  
      </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the demo working code of this code

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bbkt2eew/)**

Comment: This works, thank you Himesh, need to tweak a few things, but it's aligned horizontally.

Comment: @purpledot welcome..!! now what you want otherthing.?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your Book html (title, link, image) in one div. And set float to that div wrapper. Like this:

```
<div class="book">
    <div class="book-title"><a href="">Up Country</a></div>
    <div class="book-image"><a href=""><img src="#1" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="book">
    <div class="book-title"><a href="">The Quest</a></div>
    <div class="book-image"><a href=""><img src="#2" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="book">
    <div class="book-title"><a href="">Radiant Angel</a></div>
    <div class="book-image"><a href=""><img src="#3" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
```

And the book div will have this style:

```
.book {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following css code snippet into your code:

```
.views-row.views-row-1.views-row-odd.views-row-first {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

### Example Code

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .field-content img {
        float: left;
        padding-right: 10px;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .views-row.views-row-1.views-row-odd.views-row-first {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    
    <div class="view-content">
      <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
          <div class="views-field views-field-title">        
            <span class="field-content"><a href="/country">Up Country</a></span>  
          </div>  
          <div class="views-field views-field-field-book-image">
              <div class="field-content">
                  <a href="/country">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CFdC.jpg?s=48&g=1" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
    </a>
    
              </div>  
          </div>  
      </div>
    <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
          <div class="views-field views-field-title">        
            <span class="field-content"><a href="/country">Up Country</a></span>  
          </div>  
          <div class="views-field views-field-field-book-image">
              <div class="field-content">
                  <a href="/country">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CFdC.jpg?s=48&g=1" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
    </a>
    
              </div>  
          </div>  
      </div>
    <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
          <div class="views-field views-field-title">        
            <span class="field-content"><a href="/country">Up Country</a></span>  
          </div>  
          <div class="views-field views-field-field-book-image">
              <div class="field-content">
                  <a href="/country">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CFdC.jpg?s=48&g=1" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
    </a>
    
              </div>  
          </div>  
      </div>
    </div>    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for :P

Output screenshot : 
Added different image url for each image tag.

[image]

Comment: No, this causes the first and second image to align on top of each other then the third image off to the right of the second image. It looks like an "L" pattern.

Comment: @purpledot :  I have attached a screenshot of output, it seems to be coming fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put many ***"classes"*** and ***"divs"***. It can make you more confused and if you don't remove them, you have to put many properties in your classes. I think the codes below will solve your problem.

```css
.field-content img {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.views-field {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-content">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
      <div class="views-field">        
          <a href="/country">Up Country</a> <br/>
          <a href="/country"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="xxx.jpg" width="126" height="192" alt="" /></a>
          </div>   
          <div class="views-field">        
            <a href="/country">Up Country</a>  <br/>
              <a href="/country"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="xxx.jpg" width="126" height="192" alt="" /></a>
                 </div>
          <div class="views-field">        
          <a href="/country">Up Country</a> <br/>
              <a href="/country"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="xxx.jpg" width="126" height="192" alt="" /></a>
          </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This (html) is pre-generated by Drupal, this is not something I made by hand.

Comment: This is close the images are aligned however the title is aligned to the left of the image instead of it being positioned above the image like in the screen shot.